# _DELETE_CRT_VEC and _NEW_CRT not available VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am migrating the code base from VS2010 to VS2015, but method those were working inside VS2010  are not working under VS2015, and showing error C3861: '_DELETE_CRT_VEC': identifier not found,To resolve this error i dig the code and found that  Xdebug file  not available inside VS2015 include(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include) folder which hold the definition of _DELETE_CRT_VEC and _NEW_CRT macros which was available earlier VS2010 versions.

so can any one let me know what methods i can use in place of  in _DELETE_CRT_VEC and _NEW_CRT in  VS2015 to release DebugHeap memory?

Comment: The original need for these macros has disappeared in VS2012, the CRT no longer creates its own heap but allocates from the default process heap.  So of course they were removed from the standard C++ library implementation.  Which is what you need to do as well, good riddance.

Comment: Thanks Hans for update,so what i can use to de-allocate and allocate memory in CRT in vs2015?.do you have any idea..

Comment: Thanks Hans for update,so you means to say CRT no longer create its own heap ,means allocation and de-allocation of memory is automatically happen in **VS2015** ..**weather am i understanding correct?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Micro soft does not  _DELETE_CRT_VEC and _NEW_CRT macros from  since vs2012, instead of those macros we can use delete and new operator in vs2015. Please refer the below msdn link which shows that new and delete work same alike _NEW_CRT and  _DELETE_CRT_VEC macros. 
Here is a document about CRT Debug Heap Details for  a reference.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/974tc9t1.aspx